# Using Beautiful Soup for site that won't fully load without scrolling

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape company names from [this](http://fortune.com/fortune500/2015/list/) site, but the site does not automatically the full list of companies. When interacting through a browser, the site loads ~25 companies, then when I scroll it loads ~25 more until it reaches the end of the list. When I'm scraping the company names using Beautiful Soup, I only get 25 names.

Is there a way to scrape all the names with Beautiful Soup (or some other library in python)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data which is loading when you scroll down is an extra request URL, 'http://fortune.com/api/v2/list/1141696/expand/item/ranking/asc/20/30'

20 - number of items in current page, 30 - number of items to be obtained in next page.

If you want to get the next pages, you need to form the URL like

http://fortune.com/api/v2/list/1141696/expand/item/ranking/asc/50/30
http://fortune.com/api/v2/list/1141696/expand/item/ranking/asc/80/30
http://fortune.com/api/v2/list/1141696/expand/item/ranking/asc/110/30
and so on.

This can't be rendered in BeautifulSoup as it is a json response.

The company lists are stored in value `list-items` of the json response.